# Is it possible to get a page within an iframe to refresh the entire main page?

Tags: iframe

At the moment I run a wordpress blog and I get users to authenticate within an iframe.  However there is information in side bars that does not refresh.  Is there some way I can do a whole of page redirect to

http://wordswithfriends.net/?page_id=386

after login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `parent.location`.

`parent.location = 'http://wordswithfriends.net/?page_id=386';`

Comment: Or even more foolproof, couldn't you just do this?: `parent.location = parent.location.href`

Comment: @sdleihssirhc Because he also said "redirect", I wasn't sure whether he wanted the page to "refresh" to itself or to a different URL.

Comment: I basically want to be able to send it anywhere

Comment: @delta If that's the case, setting `parent.location` to the desired URL should work for you.